# How to append style sheet with close element using zend?

Tags: php, zend-framework, xhtml

I am using zend. When i use below code,

```
<?=  $this->headLink()
            ->appendStylesheet(BASE_URL . 'css/css.css');
 ?>
```

This outputs like below with out close element.

```
<link href="/ecomos3/css/css.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" >
```

so this one fails in w3 validation and getting "`end tag for "link" omitted, but OMITTAG NO was specified`"

i want the link tag should be

```
<link href="/ecomos3/css/css.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

How can i do it in zend ? Kindly advice on this.

Comment: You need to set the doctype to xhtml

Comment: @vascowhite I have given <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> in my page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to specify the docType using the [doctype helper](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.11/en/zend.view.helpers.html#zend.view.helpers.initial.doctype)

You can do it in your bootstrap if you wish:-

```
class Bootstrap extends Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Bootstrap
{
    protected function _initDoctype()
    {
        $this->bootstrap('view');
        $view = $this->getResource('view');
        $view->doctype('XHTML1_STRICT');
    }
}
```

Or add this line to your `config.ini` file:-

```
resources.view.doctype = "XHTML1_STRICT"
```